# Use Firebase with custom authentication (JWT)

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, jwt

I currently have a frontend (Swift, iOS) and backend (node.js) completely running. I am now looking into real time updates for certain parts of my application and I have decided to go with Firebase because it allows me to deploy quickly and scale easily later on.

However, as I already have an entire backend setup, which authenticates the user and sends back a token (JWT), I would like to know how I can use the same authentication for Firebase. The idea would be to set custom rules in Firebase based on the userID, and to use this userID (which is just a regular id, e.g. my userID is 1, not a UUID) to create collections inside the real time database and Firestore.

I have already read the [docs on custom tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens), but I am left with a couple of concerns:

- Can I use this to sign a user in, without using Firebase Auth? Or will this create a user in Firebase Auth too?
- I can only sign the JWT with an expiry for max. 60 mins from now, so one hour. Would this mean I have to re-authenticate every hour? How should I go about this? My current app grants a JWT which is valid for 21 days.
- Should I use the same JWT for Firebase as I use for my entire application, or should I generate a new one and send this one back too, with the main purpose to use it for Firebase Auth in my Swift application?

Comment: Is it sensitive data? If yes, you need to use Firebase Auth. If no, change the rules to public

Comment: Definitely. Would be used for a small type of one-on-oke chat (question > answer), so I don’t want anyone to access all records. So Firebase Auth parallel to my existing authentication system?

Answer (score 0):

The JWT needs to be generated with a different set of keys provided by Google in order for Firebase to verify the JWT. You can't use your existing JWT which was signed by another set of keys on your existing server.

But what you could do is use your existing user ids and sign them with Google's keys at the same time when signing the keys for your existing system and end up with 2 JWTs which you pass to your client.